# What type of bond(s) are present in the borohydride ion?

Tags: bond, covalent-compounds

In the $\ce{BH4-}$ ion, what bonds are present between boron and hydrogen?

Are there three covalent bonds between boron and three hydrogen atoms (using the boron 2s, 2p<sub>*x*</sub>, and 2p<sub>*y*</sub> orbitals), with the fourth hydrogen being a hydride ion $\ce{H-}$ which forms a coordinate or dative bond to the boron 2p<sub>*z*</sub> orbital?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is simply a bond between four hydrogen atoms ($\ce{H}$) and a boron anion ($\ce{B-}$). These bonds are identical to and indistinguishable from the other $\ce{B-H}$ bonds. They are all covalent bonds of length $1.21\:\mathrm{Å}$.

Your idea of $\ce{H-}$ completing $\ce{BH3}$'s $2\mathrm{p}_z$ orbital isn't quite right either. Atom's individually have atomic orbitals, but when they form bonds these atomic orbitals combine to form **molecular orbitals**. This is picture more accurately demonstrates the bonding between $\ce{B-}$ and the $\ce{H}$ atoms.

[image: MO for BH4-]

[[Photo Source](http://classes.uleth.ca/200803/chem3830a/Test2_chem3830_2008_answers.pdf)]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Borohydride ion]
<sub>(source: [mcat-review.org](http://mcat-review.org/lewis-borohydride.gif))</sub>

You are quite correct, the boron forms covalent bonding with three Hydrogens, and then a coordinate bond with H- ion (1s2)

Extra info:
This ion is fairly water soluble and acts as a ligand, using bridging hydrogens as three-centre two-electron donor atoms, forming complexes like Al(BH4)3 and Be(BH4)2

[Reference: Principles of Descriptive Inorganic Chemistry
 By Gary Wulfsberg](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=JoNUVLrNg14C&pg=PA347&lpg=PA347&dq=how%20is%20bh4-%20ion%20formed&source=bl&ots=hHFc-fV4hj&sig=V4f_lodiaPWkpifK-DZCqjROzZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAmoVChMIjsHY8rf8yAIVCxuUCh0QxQ03#v=onepage&q=how%20is%20bh4-%20ion%20formed&f=false)

Comment: what is opinion about ringo's answer?

Comment: I looked up what ringo answered, and it appears that his answer is more accurate. I am basing my answer on basic middle school chemistry, whereas his is a little more advanced. I don't know a lot, as of now, I am only in high school after all :p